# How can one plot continuous by continuous interactions in ggplot2?

Tags: r, regression, ggplot2, interaction

Let's say I have data:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100,2,10)
x2 <- rnorm(100,2,10)
y <- x1+x2+x1*x2+rnorm(100,1,2)
dat <- data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
res <- lm(y~x1*x2,data=dat)
summary(res)
```

I want to plot the continuous by continuous interaction such that x1 is on the X axis and x2 is represented by 3 lines, one which represents x2 at a Z-score of 0, one at Z-score of +1, and another at a Z-score of -1, with each line a separate color and labelled.  How can I do this using ggplot2?

For example, it might look something like this (though of course with different colored lines rather than different line types):
[image: Example Image]

Comment: Could you show an example image from an other package/software or give a more detailed description what you want to plot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my version with your simulated data set:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100,2,10)
x2 <- rnorm(100,2,10)
y <- x1+x2+x1*x2+rnorm(100,1,2)
dat <- data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
res <- lm(y~x1*x2,data=dat)
z1 <- z2 <- seq(-1,1)
newdf <- expand.grid(x1=z1,x2=z2)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=transform(newdf, yp=predict(res, newdf)), 
            aes(y=yp, x=x1, color=factor(x2))) + stat_smooth(method=lm)
p + scale_colour_discrete(name="x2") + 
  labs(x="x1", y="mean of resp") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,1)) + theme_bw()
```

I let you manage the details about x/y-axis labels and legend positioning.

[image]

Comment: Looks good, except (of course) we would need to scale(x1) and scale(x2) first.

Comment: @drknexus Yes, of course (in my initial tests, I used standardized N(0;1) variates, instead of yours).

Answer (score 5):

Computing the estimates for y with Z-score of 0 (*y0* column), -1 (*y1m* column) and 1 (*y1p* column):

```
dat$y0 <- res$coefficients[[1]] + res$coefficients[[2]]*dat$x1 + res$coefficients[[3]]*0 + res$coefficients[[4]]*dat$x1*0
 dat$y1m <- res$coefficients[[1]] + res$coefficients[[2]]*dat$x1 + res$coefficients[[3]]*-1 + res$coefficients[[4]]*dat$x1*-1
dat$y1p <- res$coefficients[[1]] + res$coefficients[[2]]*dat$x1 + res$coefficients[[3]]*1 + res$coefficients[[4]]*dat$x1*1
```

Plotting the lines with base `plot()`:

```
plot(dat$x1, dat$y0, type="l", xlab="x1", ylab="Estimates")
lines(dat$x1, dat$y1m, col="red")
lines(dat$x1, dat$y1p, col="blue")
```

[image]

To use ggplot, you may call [geom_line](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/geom_line):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x1, y0)) + geom_line() +
    geom_line(aes(x1, y1m), color="red") +
    geom_line(aes(x1, y1p), color="blue") +
    theme_bw() + opts(title="") + xlab("x1") + ylab("Estimates")
```

[image]

Comment: you can get predictions using predict.
dat[,"y0"]<-predict(res,newdata=data.frame(x1=dat[,"x1"],x2=0))
Saves a bit of typing.

Comment: @mpiktas: thank you, I did not know about `predict`, but seems useful.

Comment: I'd alway recommend using predict instead of calculating the slopes yourself - it's much simpler especially when you have interactions or non-linear components.